# Java - Change output to binary format to be read later

Tags: java, input, binary, output

Recently I have been working on a library app for technical manuals, I have managed to allow my application to save the  stored manuals to txt files, but havent been able to load these text files back into my library, so far the contents of the text file is just printed to the console.

I have heard it is easier to enable binary files to be read and loaded in java, so my question is if there is a way to change my existing code to read and write binary files, so manuals actually get restored into the library when a user loads a library.txt file.

Here is my code:

```
//Choice 7: Load Library:

            if(Menu.menuChoice == 7){
                boolean loadYesNo = Console.readYesNo("\n\nThe manualKeeper app is able to load and display any 'Library.txt' files \nfound in your home folder directory.\n\nWould you like to load and display library? (Y/N):\n");
                if(loadYesNo==true){
                try {
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader("Library.txt");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                    String str;
                    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(str + "\n");
                    }

                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("\n                    Error! No previous libraries found.");
                    System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                }

                Menu.displayMenu();
                }
                else if(loadYesNo==false){
                    System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("\n                             Library not loaded!\n");
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                    Menu.displayMenu();
                }
            }

...
                if(Menu.menuChoice == 0){
                if(Menu.menuChoice == 0){
                    if(Library.ManualList.size() > 0){
                        boolean saveYesNo = Console.readYesNo("\nThe manualKeeper app is able to save your current library to a '.txt' \nfile in your home folder directory (C:\\Users\\ 'YOUR NAME').\n\nWould you like to save the current library? (Y/N):\n");
                        if(saveYesNo==true){
                            try {
                                File file = new File("Library.txt");

                                file.createNewFile();
                                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
                                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

                                for (int i = 0; i < Library.ManualList.size(); i++){
                                    pw.println("\n-------------------- Index Number: " + i + " --------------------");
                                    pw.println(Library.ManualList.get(i).displayManual());
                                    pw.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
                                }
                                pw.close();
                                System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                                System.out.println("\n                              Library saved!\n");
                                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                                break exit;
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                System.out.println("Error! Library unable to save.");
                            }

                        }
                            else if(saveYesNo==false){
                                System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                                System.out.println("\n                              Library not saved!\n");
                                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                                break exit;
                        }
                        Menu.displayMenu();
                    }else if(Library.ManualList.isEmpty()){ 
                        Menu.displayMenu();
                    }
                }
            }               

        }
    System.out.println("\n              ~   You have exited the manualKeeper app!   ~                  ");
    System.out.println("\n                  Developed by Oscar Moore - 2014 - UWL\n");
    System.out.println("\n                                   <3\n");

}
}
```

I am new to Java so please forgive me if I have made any mistakes in my code :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First keep in mind that all data on disk is binary. How you read it is a matter of encoding/decoding those bytes. If you look at the JavaDoc for BufferedReader you will see the description says "Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines."

So the BufferedReader is setup for handling (or decoding) text. That text can be in ASCII or UTF-8 or whatever encoding...

Now what you wish to do is read the data in as binary. That's actually a lot simpler. Here's how

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;

Path libraryFile = Paths.get("path/to/Library.txt");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(libraryFile);
```

Comment: not sure why this was voted down as it clearly answers the question of reading binary data from disk